# Navigation Bar Div not fully visible because of the header

Tags: html, css, overflow

[The Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJe83.png)

So if the browser is minimized, I have this problem. I know it's because of the header (horizontal bar) but I don't know how to fix it.

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xns9sr29/

```
.BaraSus { height: 75px; width: 100%; overflow-y: hidden; background-color: rgb(116, 184, 219); }
.BaraStanga { overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto; position: fixed; background-color: rgb(140, 196, 226); height: 100%; width: 250px; }
```

Comment: You dont want the scroll. I can only see a scroll tab

Comment: I do want the scroll in case if the resolution is too small (this is not the problem). The problem is that I can't see the bottom of the scroll because of the header.